# Cannot import package in unit tests for a Jenkins Shared Library

Tags: jenkins, gradle, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I'm attempting to create unit tests for a JenkinsShared library using Gradle in order to run the  test tasks.

I've followed [this](https://medium.com/disney-streaming/testing-jenkins-shared-libraries-4d4939406fa2) tutorial which upon conclusion one has a working test suite for a shared library for functions within the `vars` folder (with the unit tests in `src/test/groovy/*Test.groovy`).

However, in our internal shared jenkins library we followed a more object oriented style and isolated functionality into a package of classes in the format: `src/org/company/*.groovy`.

The problem arises when attempting to import said package into a unit test class. In the tutorial, the functions are imported using the `loadScript` method this method fails when loading a class which is dependent on another file.

Take the class:

```
package tests

import org.junit.*
import com.lesfurets.jenkins.unit.*
import static groovy.test.GroovyAssert.*

import org.company.UtilFactory

class UtilFactoryTest extends BasePipelineTest {
    @Test
    void testCall() {
        def util = UtilFactory.getUtil("hello")
        assertEquals true, true
    }
}
```

src/org/company/UtilFactory.groovy

```
package org.company

class UtilFactory implements Serializable {
    static Util instance   

    static Util getUtil(script=null) {
        if (!(UtilFactory.instance)) {
            if (!script) {
                // Throws an exception if on the first call to getUtil the 
                // script parameter is null.
                throw new ScriptUndefinedException("script parameter null on initial call to getUtil")
            }

            UtilFactory.instance = new Util(script)
        }
        return UtilFactory.instance
    }
}

class ScriptUndefinedException extends Exception {
    // Parameterless Constructor
    public ScriptUndefinedException() {}

    // Constructor that accepts a message
    public ScriptUndefinedException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Which gives me the exception:

```
jenkins-utilities/src/test/groovy/UtilFactoryTest.groovy: 7: 
unable to resolve class org.company.UtilFactory
    @ line 7, column 1.
    import org.company.UtilFactory
```

This may be more of a Gradle issue than a JenkinsShared Library. I've just spent a good portion of my day trying to figure out exactly what I'm doing wrong to no avail.

I would really appreciate any help to guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This library may be helpful getting your shared libraries to work in the unit test https://github.com/stchar/pipeline-sharedlib-testharness